# How to add text below dates in showdatepicker flutter

Tags: flutter, date, calendar

how can I add **text below each date** in showdatepicer in the flutter mobile app. Just like price in flight booking apps. And then select a particular date. Is it possible with syncfusion datepicker or any other?

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you’ve tried so far and an image what are you trying to archive?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i have added image , do check it out